# How can i know if a variable is a number or a letter with Pascal?

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I'm trying to make a (very) little code to determine whether a given variable x is a number or a letter. It has to be done by hand without things like type(x) -assuming there is such thing in Pascal-.

My plan was to verify that x is not a number one by one, then i wrote this:

```
(*let ischar be a boolean and let x be a letter or a number.*)
for i:=0 to 9 do
begin
    if (x=i) then
        ischar = false;
end;

if ischar then
    write('x is a number!');
else
    write('x is a letter');
```

I was hoping that the test "x=i" would return false if x is a letter, but here i don't even get to compile because of the following error: "Got char, expected long int". It seems that i can't compare x and i, i knew that but i tought that under that circumstances if would return false.
Is there another way to do this 'by hand'?

Comment: A note on Pascal syntax, not related to the question: in an `if ... then ... else ...` expression, a semicolon immediately before the `else` is not allowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's generally not possible to directly compare variables of different types. The compilation error suggests `x` is declared as a `char`, while `i` is a `longint`.

The available options may depend on what Pascal compiler you use.
My only experience is with the Borland (later CodeGear and Embarcadero) products "Turbo Pascal" and "Delphi".

Those compilers have the `ord` function which gives the numeric value of an ordinal type.
In the case of a `char`, the `ord` function should give you the ASCII code of the character, which you can test to see if it's in the code range of '0'..'9'.

You don't need the `for` loop. This should work:

```
if (ord(x)<48) or (ord(x)>57) then ischar:=true else ischar:=false;
```

Edit: Here's the Free Pascal documentation for the `ord` function:
http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/ord.html

Comment: Not much to add, except that ischar is a misnomer. It is more isnotnumber. But that is more a problem of the question than of this answer

Comment: Or more concisely, ischar:= not (x in ['0'..'9']);

Comment: @No'am Newman - That certainly is more concise and produces the same result, though I've heard that set comparisons like `x in ['0'..'9']` may produce slower compiled code; I haven't tested that and it may depend on the compiler.